# I can't get my custom AvalonDock theme to work, anyone does?

Tags: wpf, theming, avalondock

I'm new to AvalonDock, but I see it's relatively easy to use. I'm planning to use it in a custom app for my company. We have a certain look'n'feel so I want to get the control to use the same colors.

I am using the ExpressionDark theme as a base, so basically what I did was to copy the AvalonDock.Themes and rename it, and change the name of the ExpressionDark theme to mine but when I compile and try to use it in my app, it says there is a missing resource key (PaneHeaderCommandStyle). If I remove my theme ResDict, it works again.

I don't understand what's wrong, since I haven't changed anything but the project and theme name. Is there anything I could be missing?

Please help...